# Connecting XAMPP to a domain and adding files

Tags: mysql, xampp

What I need is a web server hosting just for saving large files on it and share it online, so today I downloaded XAMPP Control Panel V3.2.1 as I read on a topic that it can help me.
Actually, I don't have enough knowledge about XAMPP, can I use it to upload files with normal domain(like: www.mydoamin.com/myfile)?, how can I connect the server I build with a domain after purchasing it? and how can I upload files to this domain.
Till now I done all the needed setup, and here's what I get when I start the application: [image]

Also I can use the "MySQL" in the webpage after log-in, and here's how the page looks like:
[image]

Is there any recommendation for other application that helps me uploading files to my own domain/server and share it, if this one isn't for these stuff?

Comment: I'd really, really suggest you read the documentation on the relevant pieces of software.

Comment: Dont say using "MySQL in webpage", say using "PhpMyAdmin". And btw dont use it ;-) Go for console.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is software bundle containing cross OS solutions (X) for webserver Apache (A), MySQL database (M), and server-side language PHP (P) and Perl (P).

If you got a domain you need to redirect it to IP on which this XAMPP server works. To do it call/mail your domain registrator (a company that sold you a domain) and ask about it. It involves DNS (Domain Name Server) configuration - ask them how to change DNS to direct it to your XAMPP server.

PS To add files go to `htdocs` direcotry in your XAMPP instalation or whatever you defined to store files (and websites) and drop your files in there.

As I can see you are not experienced in that kind of things so maybe ask company that sold you a domain name about "shared hosting"? It's preconfigured ready to go server where you send files over `FTP`

Comment: What company do you recommend to purchase a domain from? also should I delete the whole files that into `htdocs` then upload the files?

Comment: And what files you have in `htdocs`? I cant recommend you any company as this is not the purpouse of stackoverflow. Go to http://www.webhostingtalk.com/ to decide. PS Good host and domain providers are: those based in your country with servers in your country, that have 24/7 helpline/admin support and are not owned by other company from abroad. ;-)

Comment: Well I have `favicon`, `images`, `application`, `bitnami` text file, `restricted` subfile, `forbidden` subfile, `index` and the `xampp` subfile

Comment: Than start a Apache webserver (I don't think you will need all modules like MySQL or Tomcat in file storage solution) and open http://localhost - those files should fold into website - you can experiment with that